# Infilepicker inside a Webview

Tags: filepicker.io

I am having some issues with Ink File picker and web view. My app is inside a Web View on Iphone and there I am getting error in FilePicker. I [image: this is the error I am getting]

Can anybody explains this?

Answer (score 0):

That message indicates that "Communication iframe not found." or "Parent window not found." In this case, Filepicker can't send the results to the website where it has been run. On mobile devices this issue may occur when Filepicker runs inside an application web view and it is unable to send the results.

As a workaround use customized JS library version.

[Here](https://github.com/krystiangw/filepicker-phonegap-library%22) is PhoneGap version.